# How can I create an ansible list dynamically with the output of a sql query

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I have a playbook in which I want to backup, drop and import the some tables (as a means to update them), don't ask me why I won't just use updates and inserts, it's a complex architecture.

I want to query the postgres database to determine which tables from a specific database to perform the action for those tables.

Like:

```
- name: Create a list of STATIC TABLES to import later
  command: psql -t -A -d {{ dbname }} -U {{ dbuser }} -c "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE'"
  register: dbtables_data
```

And

```
- name: Backup all tables.
  shell: "pg_dump -U {{ dbuser }} {{ item.name }} -f {{ dbbackup_dir }}/{{ item.name }}.sql"
  with_items: "{{ dbtables_data.results }}"
```

This gives me:

```
fatal: [*.*.*.*] => with_items expects a list or a set
```

And I want to register this output into a list variable so that I can iterate and perform backups, drop and import actions.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registered variable contains a field named `stdout_lines` that you can use :

I suggest you to add temporarily a debug task to display output like that :

```
- name: Create a list of STATIC TABLES to import later
  command: psql -t -A -d {{ dbname }} -U {{ dbuser }} -c "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE'"
  register: dbtables_data

- name: Backup all tables.
  shell: "pg_dump -U {{ dbuser }} {{ item }} -f {{ dbbackup_dir }}/{{ item }}.sql"
  with_items: "{{ dbtables_data.stdout_lines }}"
```

To debug `stdout_lines` content, you can insert following task between both exising tasks :

```
- debug:
    var: dbtables_data
```

Or

```
- debug:
    msg="{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{ dbtables_data.stdout_lines | default([]) }}"
```

Another elegant way, is to [iterate directly over the results](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-the-results-of-a-program-execution) in one task by calling lookup plugin 'lines' with parameter 'with_lines'

```
- name: Backup all tables.
  shell: "pg_dump -U {{ dbuser }} {{ item }} -f {{ dbbackup_dir }}/{{ item }}.sql"
  with_lines: psql -t -A -d {{ dbname }} -U {{ dbuser }} -c "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE'"
```

Comment: `when` is evaluated for each item. To achieve what you expect, just use `with_items: "{{ dbtables_data.stdout_lines | default([]) }}"`. Also note, that bare variables are deprecated in `when` statement, so you should template it.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed `with_items` and `when` in last `debug` task

Comment: There is no need in `when` statement in this case, because it will always be true.

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm, I chose the asynchrone block, since I need the list in multiple  tasks, unless a shell or command task can execute multiple shell/commands.